# Minimum length of lines needed

Tags: graph, minimization

Suppose we have a set of N points on the cartesian plane (x_i and y_i). Suppose we connect those points with lines.
Is there any way like using a graph and something like a shortest path algorithm or minimum spanning tree so that we can reach any point starting from any point but minimizing the total length of the lines??

I though that maybe I could set the cost of the edges with the distance of a graph and use a shortest path algorithm but I'm not sure if this is possible.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, so I go for two algorithms.

First: you just want a robust algorithm, use [dijkstras algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). The only challange left is to define the edge cost. Which would be 1 for neighboring nodes, I assume.

Second: you want to use heuristics to estimate the next best node and optimize time consumption. Use [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), but you need to write a heuristic which under estimates the distance. You could use the euclidean distance to do so. The edge problematic stays the same.